# “Cyclic dependency not allowed” error on Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator

I'm currently using an Android emulator KOPLAYER (v1.4.1049) and installed the app Topps KICK on it and have been using it for a month. When a new update for the app came, and I tried logging in the game, this error came up:

[image: screenshot of the error]

> Cyclic Dependency not allowed.

I also tried contacting the TOPPS guys but to no use. I have tried the app on MEMU, Nox and BlueStack emulators too, but I get the same error.

It works fine on my Xperia Z and iPhone 6 Plus. The problem is just with Android Emulators on my laptop.

Any help I would get will be much appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like a development issue ! .. I immediately thought this question was going to be about developing an application, because that's usually when you see that !

Comment: It works Fine on my Xperia Z and iPhone 6 Plus.

The problem is just with Android Emulators on my Laptop.

Answer (score 0):

It seems an 'on the fly' compiling error. If so, nothing you can solve. Probably will soon arrive the update of the update.

Answer (score 0):

User is trying to use the app in a way where its not supported by the developers. TOS of the app strictly states that app should "not" be used with any emulation software.

Answer (score 0):

Just over a month ago topps released an update that killed emulators on all topps apps for good, Now when you isgn up on android devices they ask for the device your signing into, some phone ID... so they know its a real device. Still looking for other ways to get on

Comment: Oh. thnx for the info.

Can you please keep me updated if you get any other way to get on?

I'm trying other ways too, we can get to a solution together.

Answer (score 0):

This happens often, since now using an HTC One A9, whether it's a direct download or on parallel space. I have to update my phone's profile in my system updates, the phone reboots, and I can log into the Topps apps again. Even when this happens, I can log in on an old phone with no problem. Topps has no clue why this happens. I've given up working with them on it, and just update profile everytime it happens, sometimes once every few days, and once eight times in one day!